# Sigma Level calculation in Excel

Tags: excel-formula

I need to calculate the number of levels to then apply a formula in Excel. It's for database pages in calculating the amount of space needed for indexed tables. The formula, as it's presented by Microsoft, can be found here: 
[SQL Server Estimate Size of NonClustered Index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/estimate-the-size-of-a-nonclustered-index). 
The formula, in transcribed mode is:
`Num_Index_Pages = Sigma Level(Num_Leaf_Pages/Index_Rows_Per_Page^Level)`
I need to apply this formula in Excel to plug in many different values to find the total space needed for a database (all the tables, with indexes, adds up to the total of the database projected space requirements).
What I've done so far has not worked, and I admit that I'm not very familiar with Excel functions beyond sum...
The starting values, which will change for each table/index are as follows:

```
Num_leaf_pages=27778
Index_Rows_Per_Page=42
Non-Leaf_Levels=5
```

So, plugging in the values, I need a formula that will do the following:

```
27778/(42^5) + 27778/(42^4) + 27778/(42^3) + 27778/(42^2) + 27778/(42^1)
```

When I try to do this in Excel, I cannot get the correct value. I've looked online and have found "SUMPRODUCT" that uses "ROW" and "INDEX" and something called "INDIRECT", and I don't understand how any of these work.
Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you stated, Use SUMPRODUCT with ROW(INDIRECT()) to do the iteration:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B1/B2^ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&B3)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Scott. I have no idea how it works, but it does. :)